# Рамка выделения и выделенные объекты

Tags: javascript, html, css

Интересно стало, как работает рамка выделения, прямо как на рабочем столе:

[image]

Да и вообще, как она называется по "профессиональному"?

Набросал пример для понимания: http://jsfiddle.net/UDkf7/ (выделение работает сверху вниз && слева направо).

Встает такой вопрос, каким образом определять, какие элементы попали под выделение?

Comment: Точно не знаю, но могу предположить, что ничего лучше/проще/оптимальнее, чем пересечение прямоугольников (рамки выделения и значков) придумать нельзя. Максимум оптимизировать поиск пересечений с помощью [BSP][1] или особого расположения значков (в фиксированных ячейках таблицы). Впрочем, в масштабах рабочего стола сработает даже простой перебор.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSP_tree

Comment: @fori1ton тоже склоняюсь к пересечениям прямоугольников.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так: http://jsfiddle.net/UDkf7/1/

ЗЫ это для горизонтали, для вертикали аналогично.

Comment: @fori1ton, да, это набросок, не работа за автора ) Довести до ума труда не составит...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov вроде больше ответов нет - тогда ваш как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так, пересечение прямоугольников, 6 класс :)

```
function intersects(box_x, box_y, box_x1, box_y1, box2_x, box2_y, box2_x1, box2_y1) {
    //X not intersects
    if (box2_x > box_x1 || box2_x1 < box_x) {
        return false;
    }

    //Y not intersects
    if (box2_y > box_y1 || box2_y1 < box_y) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Шестой класс шестым классом, а если один прямоугольник будет отзеркален (x2 < x1) - функция будет крякать :)

(это существенно, т.к. при выделении в x1/y1 - точка mousedown, а не левая верхняя)

Comment: @Sh4dow не знаю, у меня всё работает прекрасно) На вход каждой точки я не собираюсь проверять. box_* - это больший прямоугольник, если это важно.

Comment: @lampa, да понятно, что полное решение - больше дело техники.

Но 1: это случай для двух прямоугольников с x/y в в левом верхнем углу; если `box_x` левее `box_x1`, то пересекающиеся прямоугольники вполне могут дать `box2_x > box_x1` (т.е., `return false`)

Но 2: собственно я чего пишу это - мне кажется, желательно писать, что решение неполное, хотя бы в духе "это для такого-то случая, остальное сами думайте, это просто".

Comment: @Sh4dow скорее наоборот, если функция содержит такую опцию, как решение отраженных прямоугольников, то это стоит указать. А если функция решает задачу пересечение прямоугольников, то и следует указать, что она решает.